# Is this an array or variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, variables

I am trying to understand the javascript part of the jquery slider whose documentation is http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/05/fullscreen-slideshow-with-html5-audio/

The first part of the gallery.js has the code below. I can't figure out whether this is a single variable assigned multiple jquery objects or an array?

```
var pictures = [], $pointer = $( '#pointer' ), $thumbnails = $( '#thumbnails' );
```

When i try the code below to find out what exactly does 'var pictures' represent it returns nothing:

```
document.write (typeof pictures);
```

Can someone please explain what it is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `document.write()` is not a good way to debug/investigate. Use `console.log()` (and the other console APIs) and the browser console's interactive command line.

Comment: Testing if a variable is an array is done by using `Array.isArray()`.  For example: `if (Array.isArray(pictures)) { /* yay! it's an array */ }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a way to declare multiple variables:

```
var pictures = [], $pointer = $( '#pointer' ), $thumbnails = $( '#thumbnails' );
```

is the same as writing:

```
var pictures = [], 
    $pointer = $( '#pointer' ), 
    $thumbnails = $( '#thumbnails' );
```

or:

```
var pictures = [];
var $pointer = $( '#pointer' );
var $thumbnails = $( '#thumbnails' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pictures = [], $pointer = $( '#pointer' ), $thumbnails = $( '#thumbnails' );
```

This is a way to define many variables at once. You will probably see it more often like:

```
var pictures = [],
    $pointer = $( '#pointer' ),
    $thumbnails = $( '#thumbnails' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pictures = [];
console.log(typeof pictures);
```

will give you 'object' as return value.

FYI,

```
var object = {};
var array = [];
```